# Swift AVPlayerViewController Remove Audio & Subtitles Button

Tags: swift, avplayer, avplayerviewcontroller

I would like to remove the Audio & Subtitles button when using the `AVPlayerViewController`. I create the controller as follows:

```
// Create the view controller and player
let moviePlayerViewController: AVPlayerViewController = AVPlayerViewController()
let moviePlayer = AVPlayer(url: videoUrl!)

// Initialize the AVPlayer
moviePlayerViewController.player = moviePlayer
moviePlayerViewController.player?.isClosedCaptionDisplayEnabled = false

// Present movie player and play when completion
self.present(moviePlayerViewController, animated: false, completion: {
    moviePlayerViewController.player?.play()
})
```

I thought `moviePlayerViewController.player?.isClosedCaptionDisplayEnabled = false` would take care of removing the button for me, but I'm wrong. Could anyone help me find the correct setting to hide the Audio & Subtitles button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [official doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1801/_index.html), you can not hide Audio&Subtitles button on default player layout. If you insist on removing that button, try to customize your own player, or modify .m3u8 file to remove redundant subtitle options.